# Read input from a csv and append that values to variable using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

```
#!/bin/bash

Dir="" 
while read line
    do echo "Record is :$line"
    Dir+="Dir,$line" 
done < dir.csv 

echo $Dir
```

where `dir.csv` is an input file here which includes following data:

```
/example/people/
/book/
/book/english/
```

I would like to append the values of the rows into one variable like
`/example/people/,/book/,/book/english/`

Is there any easy way to achieve this through shell script? above script is showing only the last value ex:`/book/english/`

Comment: Please, kindly edit the post enclosing and formatting your script in order to understand it better and give you a useful answer.

Comment: How about `tr '\n' ',' < dir.csv`

Comment: Keeping your current code structure, you have `Dir+="Dir,$line"` but you should be using `Dir="$Dir,$line"` or `Dir="$Dir${Dir:+,}$line"`, where the more complex version avoids a leading comma. This works in any shell derived from the Bourne shell (`sh`, `bash`, `zsh`, `dash`, `ksh`, …). In Bash (and probably some other modern shells), you could use `Dir+="${Dir:+,}$line"`, where the `${Dir:+,}` part adds a comma only if `Dir` is set and non-empty — avoiding the leading comma again. See [Shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see anything in your code that would cause your script to only show the last value.

This may be an illusion: is your `dir.csv` file [CRLF-delimited](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=CRLF)? (DOS/Windows format) If so, remove the CR that ends each line with a utility like `dos2unix` or a command like `tr -d '\r'`.

Some notes though:

- In `Dir+="Dir,$line"`, the string `Dir` should probably be removed (`Dir+=",$line"`).
- You probably want to get rid off the initial comma: `Dir=${Dir#,}`.
- All this can be simplified with the single command below:

```
Dir=$(paste -s -d, dir.csv)
```

... or, with CRLF line-endings:

```
Dir=$(tr -d '\r' < dir.csv | paste -s -d,)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is easier:

```
xargs < dir.csv|sed 's/ /,/g'
```

or if you have `CRLF` line endings, you can clean those up with:

```
xargs < dir.csv|tr -d '\r'|sed 's/ /,/g'
```

The above proposed `tr '\n' ',' < dir.csv` can add an additional `,` at the end if the CSV ends with newline

Comment: I would like to save all the values in the variable( ex /example/people/,/book/,/book/english/) but this also shows last row only ( ,/book/english/)

Comment: please check your line ending, or see my updated answer.